# What material will block/deflect heat from sunlight outdoors for a storage unit?

Tags: storage

did not know where else to post this, but I am sure here someone can help.

Besides insulation such as fiberglass, cellulose, styrofoam, what material similar to maybe a plastic will not absorb heat or deflect it in order to build something. Styrofoam seems to be the best after my research but it will crack or not last.

Something that I can use to build a medium size storage unit outdoors that will not break if wind throws objects around such as small rocks during storms. This way the contents of the storage will stay fairly warm (maybe 80-85) and not 102 degrees Fahrenheit.

Also something shiny would hurt the eyes/be difficult to look at outdoors if the entire structure was made with reflective sheets so reflective aluminum is not an option and there are no trees around.

Right now I have a plastic storage unit and the temp. will go above 100 Fahrenheit (I used a thermometer to check). So in a nutshell, I would like to build a big box that resists/deflects/does not absorb heat with durable lightweight material.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you're trying to protect from the sun's heat; would you add a picture? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aluminum storage shed and line the INSIDES of it with Styrofoam, glued to it with construction adhesive. The aluminum walls shield the Styrofoam from physical damage, the Styrofoam slows the heat transfer from the aluminum. You can also paint the outside with "heat reflective paint" (use your favorite search engine on that term for a supplier near you). Heat reflective paint works by having a substance like tiny hollow balls of aluminum  (varies by manufacturer) suspended in the paint that reflects infrared energy, without necessarily reflecting visible light, so it's not "shiny". I've used some that was a beige color on a steel shipping container, it immediately dropped the temperature inside by about 20 deg. F on a hot sunny day.

Comment: Thank you for this info!! This will solve my problem!! I went out and looked for heat reflective paint at a Home Depot and Lowes, they gave me a puzzled look as they never heard of it. I also looked online to order, and it is available but in Australia. Any brand or link to where I can buy it online? I did find insulating additves for paint (Insuladd) but dont know if they work well, thanks!

Comment: It's not proper in thjis site to make brand name recommendations. Try searching for "IR reflective paint"

Answer (score 0):

Even a coat of cheap white paint will make a significant difference or consider providing something to shade the storage unit: trees & bushes are very effective or a canvas screen.